Rotary encoder filter schematic unclear
I have a PEC11R-4215F-S0024 rotary encoder and want to build a filter circuit but I do not understand which parts of the schematic are connected to their respective pins. Additionally I only see 4 terminals A, B, 5V and Common. Where is the ground pin though and are these labels somehow the pins? I am confused can someone perhaps draw the schematic with the pins going out of the rotary encoder pins?
https://www.electrokit.com/upload/product/41017/41017819/PEC11R.pdf


A rather poor drawing from a reputable manufacture. This kind of confusion is what I expect from hobbyist grade parts.
My interpretation:
The dashed lines represent the encoder. The encoder has 3 electrical terminals: A = encoder A switch, B = encoder B switch, C = Common. This should have been made clearer in the separate switch drawing. The remaining two terminals are the push-button switch.
The component has no resistors or capacitors, these are to be added by the user.
The nets labeled terminal are confusing. These apparently are the newly created terminals of the user created module with the resistors and caps.
When I am unsure, I use an ohmmeter to be confirm my understanding of a component like this.


Your rotary encoder has a common pin, as shown in your picture, you should connect it to ground.
The name "Terminal" seems a bit misleading here, I would refere to them as "Channels" as shown in the datasheet:

Here you can see how you should add resitors and capacitors to the encoder:

If you want to use the push button, use the pins 1 and 2.
