What would a schematic look like for this reference design?
I tried recreating this suggested filter circuit for a Bourns PER56 ring encoder on a breadboard with my Particle Photon 2 (amateur here). Connecting Pins A and B directly to the Particle's pins seems to work, and I'm able to read the data, but I would like to utilize the suggested filter circuit to prevent noise. However, I'm very stuck on how I would do this since the schematic does not seem clear to me. There's a wire going to Terminal A, but then there's also a wire going to the encoder?! Am I missing something? Would someone be able to quickly draw up a schematic that shows what the data sheet is trying to convey?


other than labeling TERMINAL B as "TERMINAL B"  there's nothing I would change.

Terminal C is the ground reference for the signals from terminals A and B.  It would connect to your Particle Photon's Ground.

as the switch rotates from 0 to open cct. the filter changes from 0.1ms to 0.2ms as a debounce filter.

Another similar question and answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/713923/rotary-encoder-filter-schematic-unclear/713926#713926

Terminals A and (presumably) B are the new filtered encoder signals you'll feed into your other circuitry instead of connecting the encoder's pins A & B there.

It's hard to get clearer than what the schematic currently shows. You have a pull-up into an RC filter to debounce the signal. The surrounding circuitry connects to the encoder as shown and the terminals marked as "Terminal A" and "Terminal B" are where the respective signals are available. The connections into the dashed box are the existing terminals on the encoder.
You can also omit the circuitry and debounce the signal in software.

Do you mean 'debounce'?

I would never slander the signal.
